# How do Jehovah Witnesses support scripturely the idea that humans will live on earth after death?

Tags: biblical-basis, jehovahs-witnesses, afterlife, earth

A Jehovah Witness and I spoke the other day and he explained to me that JWs believe that we'll live on earth after we die.

What scripture, if any, do they use to back this belief?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea comes from Revelation 21

[Revelation 21:1 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021:1&version=NIV)

> 1 Then I saw “a new heaven and a new earth,” for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and there was no longer any sea.

The problem with interpreting Revelation is that there's a lot of debate on what it actually means.

Will we live on a new earth?  **Yes** in the sense that God will give us a place to live.

Will it be identical to the old earth (with tornadoes, volcanoes, etc)?  Who knows!

The [New World Translation of this](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/revelation/21/) doesn't really vary.  You can read that if you'd like.

Comment: Oh WOW. You just made an excellent connection to Walt Browns flood evidence. The earth being without oceans when it was first created. Nice! http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/790/what-is-the-archaeological-evidence-for-a-global-flood/796#796

Comment: I agree we're not sure if the new earth is our current earth "born again" or an entirely new planet, in that sense. (Although I believe the greek word is the same for being born again when becoming a believer.) However, I'm not sure natural disasters are considered possible in the new earth, as this would pain and suffering, for which there will be no place (Rev 21:4).

Comment: I agree, unless God explicitly told us when they would come so that we could go and experience them safely.  Just a thought.  Basically, we don't really know much about the eternal place that God is preparing for us.

Comment: 2 Peter 3:10-12 says all the elements will be destroyed with intense heat.  So we can at least say it will be a "new earth" from that perspective.

Answer (score 10):

Jehovah's Witnesses, as myself, believe in an earthly paradise.  This paradise will be the restoration of what Adam and Eve lost when they sinned. We view [Psalms 37:11, 29](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalms%2037:11,%2029&version=NIV) as a prophecy of this restoration. Jesus will rule from heaven the humankind with 144000 corulers, including resurrected, for 1000 years. We believe that some prophecies for this time are the following:

**Isaiah 45:18** (all quotations from the NIV)

> For this is what the LORD says— he who created the heavens,    he is
> God; he who fashioned and made the earth,    he founded it; he did not
> create it to be empty,    but formed it to be inhabited— he says: “I
> am the LORD,    and there is no other.

**Psalm 72:16**

> May grain abound throughout the land;    on the tops of the hills may
> it sway. May the crops flourish like Lebanon    and thrive like the
> grass of the field.

**Isaiah 33:24**

> No one living in Zion will say, “I am ill”;    and the sins of those
> who dwell there will be forgiven.

**Revelation 21:4**

> He will wipe every tear from their eyes. There will be no more death’
> or mourning or crying or pain, for the old order of things has passed
> away.

**Isaiah 65:17-24**

> 17 “See, I will create    new heavens and a new earth. The former
> things will not be remembered,    nor will they come to mind. 18 But
> be glad and rejoice forever    in what I will create, for I will
> create Jerusalem to be a delight    and its people a joy. 19 I will
> rejoice over Jerusalem    and take delight in my people; the sound of
> weeping and of crying    will be heard in it no more.
> 20 “Never again will there be in it    an infant who lives but a few
> days,    or an old man who does not live out his years; the one who
> dies at a hundred    will be thought a mere child; the one who fails
> to reach[a] a hundred    will be considered accursed. 21 They will
> build houses and dwell in them;    they will plant vineyards and eat
> their fruit. 22 No longer will they build houses and others live in
> them,    or plant and others eat. For as the days of a tree,    so
> will be the days of my people; my chosen ones will long enjoy    the
> work of their hands. 23 They will not labor in vain,    nor will they
> bear children doomed to misfortune; for they will be a people blessed
> by the LORD,    they and their descendants with them. 24 Before they
> call I will answer;    while they are still speaking I will hear.

For more information for JW view on this topic you can download the book *What Does the Bible Really Teach?* and read chapter 8 from [here](https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/?contentLanguageFilter=en&pubFilter=bh&sortBy=1) in pdf format or [here](https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/bible-teach/what-is-gods-kingdom/) in html.

Comment: The idea that we'll live in paradise is, to my knowledge, a common theme throughout all denominations of Christianity.  The idea that it's an earthly paradise shouldn't be a far stretch for anyone, in my opinion.  +1 Nice answer!

Answer (score 8):

Jehovah's witnesses will also use other bible texts to back up the idea of a 'paradise earth', although the exact combination of these two words do not appear in the bible and sometimes discussion can arise about the 'correct' interpretation of the word 'land/earth'.

The most important ones (or the first that come to my mind) are:

- Matthew 5:5 (NWT, part of Jesus' sermon on the mountain):

'Happy are the mildtempered ones since they will inherit the earth'

- Matthew 6:10 (part of Jesus' model prayer, NWT):

'Let your will take place as in heaven, also upon earth.'

- 2 Peter 3:11 (NWT):

'But there are new heavens and a new earth that we are awaiting according to his promise, and in these righteousness is to dwell.'

This idea of a new heaven and earth is also already known in the OT, e.g. Isaiah 66:22.

OT texts that stress a 'promised land' or the idea that the earth or righteous ones who inhabit it, will remain for ever, are also used to support the idea of a paradise earth: e.g. Deuteronomy 30:20; Psalm 37:29, Proverbs 2:21-22 (or a contrario Proverbs 10:30) and Ecclesiastes 1:4.

JW's further point to certain OT texts that heavily stress that humans have an earthly destination or that the earth is destined to be inhabited, e.g.:

- Psalms 115:16 (NWT): 'As regards the heavens, to Jehovah the heavens belong, but the earth he has given to the sons of men.'
- Isaiah 45:18 (NWT): '...God, the Former of the earth and the Maker of it, who did not simply create it for nothing, who formed it even to be inhabited.' See also Genesis 1:28 (NWT): 'fill the earth and subdue it'.

Note: the difference in rewards for the faithful ones (eternal life in heaven or eternal life on a paradise earth) is based on a special interpretation of John 10:16 (the 'other sheep' are not interpreted as non-Jews, but as persons who look forward to live for ever on paradise earth and not in heaven).